# I m struggling to understand math, please give me advice

Tags: education, advice

I'm desperate! I need your advice. I score A's on all math courses in high school. But  I'm very depressed, because I find myself still bad at math. Reason for that is because I'm forced to rely on tools for maths that other people have invented. I Know how to use this tools and solve math problems, but I cant invent tools on my own to solve new problems that I havent faced before.

Is there any possibility to develop skillset to be able to invent your own solving methods for math problems. My dream is to become excellent mathematician, but i think my hopes are doomed. I m so depressed over this matter that i have even considered suicide, because math is ALL i m interested in life, but i dont want to just study other peoples work, i want also to invent on my own. Please give me advice.
PS.I Pretty much strugle to understand where basic consepts come from

Comment: Hi! I graduated in mathematics this year so I don't consider myself an expert. However In my experience, the ability to "create" new ways to solve new problems comes from experience rather than knowledge, and experience comes from working a lot in mathematics, in many areas, many many hours.

Comment: i suggest taking one or two courses in discrete mathematics, mostly so you can learn basic proof techniques and the fundamental logic involved. Then, reading lots and lots of proofs, getting familiar with the creative tools and approaches otehrs use. Over time you will absorb these tools into your own toolbelt and find yourself using them when necessary

Comment: Would you think you were a bad carpenter because you haven't invented tools to replace the saw, hammer, and lathe? You are learning tools that have been developed over millennia by other humans, a remarkable history of some truly brilliant people who have gifted us with these tools. It is hard to invent a "new" tool, although we all try. The best most of us manage is to reinvent tools found before. :)

Comment: Firstly and foremost, if you've seriously considered suicide about this then you should seriously consider seeing a therapist, assuming you're living in a country with decent mental healthcare. There is no shame in doing so. I love studying maths. I greatly enjoy doing so, and I have spent tens of thousands of hours studying it. But I would much rather give it up than consider such dark things. If worst comes to the worst then give up maths and try something else. That would by no means suggest that you're a failure: people change what they do all the time!

Comment: Inventing new tools to solve new problems can be hard, because there have already been so many people doing this for thousands of years.  Don't worry for now about whether it's been done before.  Just put in a lot of practice and ask yourself questions occasionally.  It's OK if you don't have the answers immediately.  It's really OK. If you love math, just do it because it makes you happy. It's hard to learn anything if you only think about your whole life future.  I'd also suggest talking to mental health professionals about your depression. You might also try mindfulness meditation. Cheers

Comment: Secondly, I have at many occasions, wished that I could be the "maths hero" and invent a new branch of breakthrough maths, but I have to agree with Brian here: the only way to give yourself a realistic chance of creating new maths is to study it for decades. And even then you may not succeed. So being the "maths hero" is a huge goal and you're setting yourself up for failure. In my opinion, you should study maths if and only if you *enjoy studying maths*, that is, you enjoy the journey of problem-solving, as that is what maths is (to me, at least).

Comment: Developing new mathematics is much less about raw talent than it is about how much effort you put into it and how curious you are. Put deliberate effort into learning mathematics over many years and you will get better. The growth is exponential. You spend years feeling like you know nothing but once you starting improving, the rate of improvement becomes faster and faster.

Comment: Thank for your replies. I do feel better now.